# Exam: How to replace every word with a dummy one on demand?

Tags: exam

Many times, I need to print an exam with a public printer to check its format and layout. However, it would be great to have a switch that replaces all the text with dummy text so that the exam confidentiality couldn't be breached.

For the sake of completeness, it would be perfect if the long text can be replaced by a long dummy text and vice versa for the short question text. In other words, the replacement needs to be done on word basis.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[7] 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5] some text to be replaced by a dummy text
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[3] to be replaced by a dummy text
            \begin{subsubparts}
                \subsubpart[1] some question to be replaced by a dummy text
            \end{subsubparts}
        \end{subparts}
     \begin{choices}
        \choice a short text to be replaced by a short one.
     \end{choices}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470479/in-latex-is-there-good-way-to-optionally-redact-certain-sections-of-a-document  The duplicate link only handles the conditional part.  The rest comes from the comments.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks but I don't want to censor or blackout any text. I just need a switch to turn every word into a dummy one.

Comment: I figured redacting would be easier (already solved problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute-force (and quite slow) solution can be adapted from here: [How to do multiple string replacements?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153215/how-to-do-multiple-string-replacements)

Basically, I'm defining an `obfuscate` environment, so every alphabetical character is replaced by a lowercase X

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{environ}
\def\obfuscatetext{0}
\newcommand{\xeverywhere}[2]{%
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\BODY}{#1}{#2}[\BODY]%
}
\NewEnviron{obfuscate}{{%
\ifnum\obfuscatetext=1 
    \expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\BODY}{a}{x}[\BODY]%
    \xeverywhere{b}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{c}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{d}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{e}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{f}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{g}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{h}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{i}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{j}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{k}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{l}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{m}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{n}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{o}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{p}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{q}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{r}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{s}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{t}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{u}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{v}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{w}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{y}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{z}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{A}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{B}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{C}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{D}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{E}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{F}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{G}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{H}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{I}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{J}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{K}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{L}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{M}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{N}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{O}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{P}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{Q}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{R}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{S}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{T}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{U}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{V}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{W}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{Y}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{X}{x}%
    \xeverywhere{Z}{x}%
    \BODY
\else 
    \BODY
\fi 
}}
\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\let\oldtextit\textit
\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\oldtextbf{\begin{obfuscate}#1\end{obfuscate}}}
\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{\oldtextit{\begin{obfuscate}#1\end{obfuscate}}}
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\oldtexttt{\begin{obfuscate}#1\end{obfuscate}}}
\newcommand{\ObfuscateON}{%
\renewcommand{\obfuscatetext}{1}
}
\newcommand{\ObfuscateOFF}{%
    \renewcommand{\obfuscatetext}{0}
}
\ObfuscateON
\begin{document}
%If I want normal text, I just delete the next line:
\ObfuscateON
\begin{obfuscate}
\begin{questions}
    \question[7] 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5] some text to be replaced by a dummy text
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[3] to be replaced by a dummy text
            \begin{subsubparts}
                \subsubpart[1] some question to be replaced by a dummy text
            \end{subsubparts}
        \end{subparts}
     \begin{choices}
        \choice a short text to be replaced by a short one.
     \end{choices}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{obfuscate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Numbers and punctuation signs can be added *ad libitum* in the definition of `obfuscate`

EDIT: I added the \ObfuscateON command. `obfuscate` will do nothing by default, so it will only work if \ObfuscateON is used. I also patched the definitions of `\textbf`, `\textit`, and `\texttt` so `obfuscate` works.

EDIT AGAIN: As my first solution has so many bugs, I've come up with a nice solution using `lualatex` and `chickenize` which avoid clashes with other packages. As for graphics, using `draft` option suffices.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\begin{luacode*}
    chickenizefraction = 100000
    chickenstring[1] = "ayyyy"
    chickenstring[2] = "lol"
    chickenstring[3] = "lmao"
    chickenstring[4] = "haha"
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
%Delete chickenize or use \unchickenize to get normal text
\chickenize
\begin{questions}
    \question[7] 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text. 
    some  very long question body to be replaced by a very long dummy text.
    \begin{parts}
        \part[5] some text to be replaced by a dummy text
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart[3] to be replaced by a dummy text
            \begin{subsubparts}
                \subsubpart[1] some question to be replaced by a dummy text
            \end{subsubparts}
        \end{subparts}
     \begin{choices}
        \choice a short text to be replaced by a short one.
     \end{choices}
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: A really better solution]

Comment: I am away from PC to experiment but is it possible to make the replacement conditionally done by a command on my demand?

Comment: @Diaa I've added the switching command. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for this beautiful answer.

Comment: I just found one bug; it doesn't detect uppercase letters and words inside `\textbf` for example.

Comment: @Diaa Please, see the code again. I've corrected this issue.

Comment: I have just moved away from PC after asking a new question about this issue with more complex example of table with figure to be replaced by a dummy one. I would be grateful if you could check my newly asked question and help me fix the error.

Comment: Thanks again for improving the answer. However, I got this error for your 2nd edit: `File 'chickenize.tex' not found. \input{chickenize}`.

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX? As far as I know, TeXLive2019 compiles without any problems. If you can install it from your distribution, try this first. Otherwise, `chickenize` is here: https://ctan.org/pkg/chickenize so you put the files and your document in the same folder. You can also compile via Overleaf, in case neither of the previous options work.

Comment: [This document](https://pastebin.com/z8bwj5cz) gives the following error: `Package keyval Error: align undefined. ...s[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-a}`. My main document has many figures, so it is not an easy job to comment them out every time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103022/discussion-between-jairoaraujo-and-diaa).