# exam/chickenize: How to convert every single word and image into a dummy one?

Tags: fonts, exam, chickenize

Following-up [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523290/2288), I would like to make the command `\chickenize`:

1. apply the draft option of `graphicx`
2. convert every word such as `Question 1`, the text inside the table, `super` and `sub` into a dummy one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chickenize}
\begin{luacode*}
    chickenizefraction = 100000
    chickenstring[1] = "xxxx"
    chickenstring[2] = "x"
    chickenstring[3] = "xx"
    chickenstring[4] = "xxxxx"
\end{luacode*}

\qformat{Question \thequestion\hfill}

\begin{document}

\chickenize

\begin{questions}
    \question[7] 
    some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{super} \textsubscript{sub}. 

    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}\vspace{\baselineskip}

    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline
    some text\\
    another text\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

### Update 1

Considering the suggestion in Therese's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527502/exam-chickenize-how-to-convert-every-single-word-and-image-into-a-dummy-one?noredirect=1#comment1334163_527502) that refers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266775/2288), the following approach (using a conditional `\ifPublicPrinter`) needs to:

1. transform all the math text/symbols/numbers
2. remove the printed path of the draft image

[image]

```
\newif\ifPublicPrinter
\PublicPrintertrue

\ifPublicPrinter
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\fi

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{luacode,fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx}

\ifPublicPrinter
\setmainfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\fi

\qformat{Question \thequestion\ (\totalpoints)\hfill}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[7] 
        some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{super} \textsubscript{sub}. 

        \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}\vspace{\baselineskip}

        \underline{$\symbf{\Delta V \leq 5}~ \si{\kilo\m\per\hour}$}

        \[\num{-8e-06}~N_e^2 +  {0.072}~N_e - \beta\]

        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \hline
            some text\\
            another text\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do any of the options at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266775 help you?

Comment: @Thérèse I think it will help, but could you please provide an answer with a single command that transforms both the text and the images simultaneously?

Comment: @Thérèse Please, consider my last question update.

Comment: Idea: Switch to an exotic or foreign font, that does not make sense in this context.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner that's what I exactly did in my question update. However, I can't make it work perfectly everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Steven's [inspiring answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528894/2288), the following is exactly what I need:

[image]

```
\newif\ifPublicPrinter
\PublicPrintertrue

\ifPublicPrinter
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
\fi

\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{luacode,fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math,siunitx}

\ifPublicPrinter
\setmainfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}%
[range = {up , it , bb , bbit , scr , cal , bfcal , frak , tt , sfup ,
    sfit , bfup , bfit , bfscr , bffrak , bfsfup , bfsfit, {"002B}, {"002D}, {"2796}, {"207B}}]

\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{example-image}}
\fi

\qformat{Question \thequestion\ (\totalpoints)\hfill}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[7] 
        some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{super} \textsubscript{sub}. 

        \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image}\vspace{\baselineskip}

        \underline{$\symbf{\Delta V \leq 5}~ \si{\kilo\m\per\hour}$}

        \[\num{-8e-06}~N_e^2 +  {0.072}~N_e - \beta\]

        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \hline
            some text\\
            another text\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not fully clear the extent and purpose of your desired output, so I take a stab and will await feedback on what you really want.

What I do here is replace every catcode 11 token with `example-image` that is stretched and scaled to take up the same footprint as the original letter.

As to figures, I redefine `\includegraphics` to always output a generic image, rather than that which was specified.

Note that certain types of text need to be escaped between `|` delimiters, to avoid the substitution, such as environment names and macro arguments.  That is up to the user to make sure of.

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{tokcycle,graphicx}
\tokcycleenvironment\chickenize
{\tctestifcatnx a##1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{##1}%
  \edef\tmp{[width=\the\wd0, height=\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax]}%
  \addcytoks[1]{\expandafter\raisebox\expandafter{\expandafter-\the\dp0}}%
  \addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\includegraphics\tmp{example-image-a}}}}{%
  \addcytoks{##1}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}

\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{example-image-c}}
\begin{document} 
\chickenize
This is a \textit{test} of descenders yig.

Of a substitute font with math: 

|\hspace{.5in}|$y = mx^{2x} + b_{a}$

|\begin{questions}|
    \question[7] 
    some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{super} \textsubscript{sub}. 

    |\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}|%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}

    |\begin{tabular}{c}|
    \hline
    some text\\
    another text\\
    \hline
|\end{tabular}|

|\end{questions}|
\endchickenize
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wanted the output to be text rather than scaled images, here I simply replace every catcode 11 token with an `x`.  Additionally, I convert every numerical digit to a `0`, while leaving all other punctuation as is.

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{tokcycle,graphicx}
\tokcycleenvironment\chickenize
{\tctestifcatnx a##1{%
  \addcytoks{x}}{%
  \tctestifnum{`##1>`/}{\tctestifnum{`##1<`:}{%
    \addcytoks{0}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
{\processtoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}

\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{example-image-c}}
\begin{document} 
\chickenize
This is a \textit{test} of descenders yig.

Of a substitute font with math: 

|\hspace{.5in}|$y = mx^{2x} + b_{5}$

|\begin{questions}|
    \question[7] 
    some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{super} \textsubscript{sub}. 

    |\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}|%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}

    |\begin{tabular}{c}|
    \hline
    some text\\
    another text\\
    \hline
|\end{tabular}|

|\end{questions}|
\endchickenize
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In comments, the OP was not happy over the notion of having to escape many macro arguments.  The problem, of course, is that some macro arguments, like `\begin{tabular}`, you don't want to `\chickenize`, whereas some, like `\textit{test}`, you do.  In the end, the user must decide how to proceed, but below I offer an alternative, in which all group content is explicitly omitted from chickenization.  Thus, one no longer has to escape `\begin{tabular}`, for example.

However, optional macro arguments, delimited with `[...]` must still be escaped (such as the `\includegraphics` option in the MWE below).  Further, if one wishes to selectively, chickenize a macro argument, then it must be re-invoked via nesting (as in the case of `\textit{\chickenize test\endchickenize}`).

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{tokcycle,graphicx}
\tokcycleenvironment\chickenize
{\tctestifcatnx a##1{%
  \addcytoks{x}}{%
  \tctestifnum{`##1>`/}{\tctestifnum{`##1<`:}{%
    \addcytoks{0}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}{\addcytoks{##1}}}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}
{\addcytoks{##1}}

\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{\svincludegraphics[#1]{example-image-c}}
\begin{document} 
\chickenize
This is a \textit{\chickenize test\endchickenize} of descenders yig.

Of a substitute font with math: 

\hspace{.5in}$y = mx^{\chickenize2x\endchickenize} + b_{\chickenize5\endchickenize}$

\begin{questions}
    \question[7] 
    some  text  to be replaced by a dummy one \textsuperscript{%
  \chickenize super\endchickenize} \textsubscript{\chickenize sub\endchickenize}. 

    \includegraphics|[width=0.25\linewidth]|{example-image-a}%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}

    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline
    some text\\
    another text\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{questions}
\endchickenize
\end{document}
```

---

p.s.  For another related answer using this (`tokcycle`) package, in the event that you wish to replace each letter with a different letter: [LaTeX Uglifier / obfuscator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450795/latex-uglifier-obfuscator/505420#505420)

Comment: I aim to have a dummy output while keeping the same page format and layout by only converting the real text and images into dummy ones via a single command (e.g. \chickenize or setting \ifPublicPrinter to true). So, I would be grateful if there is an easier approach to "dummify" the document without having to enclose every single macro/environment with |.

Comment: @Diaa One problem would be how to differentiate `\begin{tabular}`, which you would not want to chickenize, from `\textit{italic text}`, which you would like to chickenize.  I can easily turn off the chickenizing of arguments, but that would then overlook the latter case.  In addition, optional arguments would still be a problem, as the use of `[...]` syntax may or may not imply an optional argument, and there is no trivial way I can trap `[...]` in the same way I can easily trap `{...}`.  Further, my technique would break hyphenization, and so the layout could change.

Comment: I understand. On the other side, for my question update #1, could you suggest me how to implement alfC's answer in it using lualatex with unicode-math?

Comment: @Diaa While I am not a lualatex user myself, the approach I provide works just fine in lua, and with `unicode-math`, I believe.  Thus, you could perhaps merge the two answers to better achieve what you are looking for.  I will also edit my answer to give some guidance about not processing group content.

Answer (score 1):

In your Update, to apply the font to all the math text/symbols/numbers you can add the following `setmathfont` commands:

```
\ifPublicPrinter
\setmainfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathrm]{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{redacted-script-light.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{redacted-script-bold.ttf}
\setmathfont[range={"2032}]{redacted-script-regular.ttf}
\fi
```

Comment: Applying your code, [this document](https://pastebin.com/U7HGvmi8) doesn't compile and gives errors when compiling using lualatex.